# Opencart is it possible to store products in cart in DB

Tags: php, database, cookies, opencart

Now products in cart saved through cookies.

The shopping cart must be assigned to the user not through
cookies, but through the database. Items in the shopping cart must be stored permanently until they are deleted.

Is it possible? Is there a turnkey solution?

Comment: Yes it can be stored. You can search in OS marketplace even free extension by name "Abandoned Cart"